# getpid e getuid diferentes de zero para o root

Tags: c

Estou com o seguinte problema. Ao executar:

```
void main(void){
uid_t getuid(void);
gid_t getgid(void);

uid_t user_id;
gid_t group_id;

printf("user_id: %d\n",user_id);
printf("group_id: %d\n",group_id);
exit(0);
}
```

Tenho como retorno:

```
user_id: 134513819,group_id: -1216946176.
```

Não era para retornar

```
user_id: 0,group_id: 0.
```

Tendo em vista que o arquivo pertence ao root e está sendo executado como root.

Answer (score 3):

Você parece estar declarando as funções (e não chamando) nas duas primeiras linhas, e depois você está declarando duas variáveis sem jogar nenhum valor nelas, então naturalmente elas conterão valores aleatórios.

Você teria de fazer algo como

```
user_id = getuid();
```

Se o compilador reclamar que a função não existe, é porque falta incluir

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

no início do programa (não ficou claro se você tinha colocado isso ou não).

Comment: Resolvido. Era só atribuir ao user_id=getuid() e pronto. Obrigado e quanto as bibliotecas estavam inclusas.